# How to show Label "In Stock" or "Out Of stock" in New Products Homepage

Tags: stock, out-of-stock, stock-status

i want to show Availability label "In Stock" or "Out Of stock" in my homepage product display.
do you know how to do this? thankyou

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
// $_item->getProductId() -> your product id
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());

if ($product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()) { 
    // $product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 1
    echo "product is in stock";
}else{
    // $product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 0
    echo "product is not in stock";
}

**Method 2**

$stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
if($stockItem->getIsInStock())
{
    //in stock!
}
else
{
    //not in stock!
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but where i can find the code?

Comment: You add this code in your phtml file

Comment: what phtml? catalog/product/list.phtml? catalog/product/view.phtml?

Comment: which phtml you call home page there you have to place